# Grouping all query results into a single row

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Say for example, I have a simple Blog with tags. I have a Blog table, a Tag table, and a TagRelation table. I want to run a single query and get all the relevant data for each Blog post in its own single row, including tags.

```
SELECT Tag.id AS 'Tag.id', Tag.name AS 'Tag.name', Blog.id AS 'Blog.id', Blog.author AS 'Blog.author', Blog.title AS 'Blog.title', Blog.content AS 'Blog.content' 
FROM Blog 
INNER JOIN TagRelation ON TagRelation.target = Blog.id
INNER JOIN Tag ON Tag.id = TagRelation.Tag
WHERE Blog.id = '101'
```

This query will give me a row for each Tag, each with the same Blog post data for post id 101, and adding a `GROUP BY Blog.id` will give me only one row, but whatever is the arbitrarily first Tag result.

What I want is something like this:

```
Blog.id | Blog.author | Blog.title | Blog.content | Tag.id | Tag.name | Tag.id | Tag.name 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
101     | someone     | something  | lolstuff     | 1      | tag1     | 2      | tag2
```

So that my client-side code can parse it easily into objects. Is this possible in MySQL without handling multiple matching rows for the same Blog id or doing subqueries just to get the Tags for each post? (the actual database is of course bigger and more complex than this, and I want to do as much in joins as possible.)

Comment: You can't do that in a general case (assuming an arbitrary number of tags for one given blog post). But would it be really easier to iterate over columns instead of rows in your application code?

Answer (score 1):

An approaching solution involving the use of [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(Tag.id SEPARATOR ',') AS 'Tag.ids',
    GROUP_CONCAT(Tag.name SEPARATOR ',') AS 'Tag.names',
    Blog.id, Blog.author, Blog.title, Blog.content
FROM Blog 
INNER JOIN TagRelation ON TagRelation.target = Blog.id
INNER JOIN Tag ON Tag.id = TagRelation.Tag
WHERE Blog.id = '101'
GROUP BY Blog.id
```

This results in two coma-separated lists of the corresponding `Tag.id`'s and `Tag.name`'s in the columns `Tag.ids` and `Tag.names` respectively.

But again, would it be really easier to iterate over columns (or coma-separated values in this case) instead of rows in your application code?

Comment: I forgot to mention this in my post. You're right, I could get it done with group_concat, iterating through the strings, or run a second query for each blog post to get tags and iterate through that, but I'm here looking for a more clever/elegant/faster solution.